# Vue3 WatchEffect changes prop indirectly?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

I have a question regarding the Vue 3 reactivity and mutation of props.

The following code takes a Person Object as prop. After making the prop to a Ref I create a computed property out of it. In the template below I have a list of Tasks to assign to the given Person. When I add or remove a Task the Person Object gets updated in the Parent component even though the `emit` of the computed property is not being triggered.

I guess this happens because of the logic contained in the `watchEffect` function. But if this is the case I do update the prop which is something I should not do right? Vue however does not give a warning the the prop is being updated.

Can someone tell me if this is a valid way of doing this or is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface PersonTaskLinkProps {
  modelValue: Person;
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<PersonTaskLinkProps>(), {});
const { modelValue } = toRefs(props);
const taskStore = useTaskStore();

const personModel = computed({
  get: () => {
    return modelValue.value;
  },
  set: (value) => {
    emit('update:modelValue', value);
  },
});

const selectedTasks = ref<TaskDTO[]>(
  personModel.value.taskIds.map(
    (taskId) => taskStore.getEntityById(taskId)! || []
  )
);

watchEffect(() => {
  personModel.value.taskIds = selectedTasks.value.map((task) => task.id);
});

const allTasks: TaskDTO[] = taskStore.allEntities;

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: 'update:modelValue', value: Person): void;
}>();
</script>
<template>
  <h5>Link Tasks</h5>
  <MultiSelect
    :title="$t('person.linkTasks')"
    v-model:selected-items="selectedTasks"
    :selectable-items="allTasks"
    options-label="title"
    options-value="id"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: You should copy your prop into a data variable. This way the reactivity of the computed variable is not active :)

Comment: If you don't give any feedback to answers there will me less motivation for ppl to answer you ever again in the future

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `readonly` (described in the end).

In my example I mutate with button click but there's no difference where the model property is mutated (could be in `watchEffect`).
The first mutation happens in a `watchEffect` by the way.

Vue sets the properties' object (not a property itself!) as read-only like `Object.freeze()` does. It's shallow, while you cannot override a property you can change any object properties inside it if it's an object.
From MDN on `Object.freeze()`:

> Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen.

I've prepared a gist:

```
<script setup>

import {toRefs, computed, watchEffect} from 'vue';
  
const props = defineProps(['modelValue']);
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
const {modelValue} = toRefs(props);
   
const value = computed({
  get(){
    return modelValue.value;
  },
  set(value){
    console.log(value)
    emit('update:modelValue', value);
  }
});

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('watch effect here');
  modelValue.value.property = 'watchEffect'; 
});
                       
function updateModelProperty(e){
    modelValue.value.property = e.target.textContent;
}
  
function updateModel(e){
    value.value = {property: e.target.textContent};
} 
                  
function updateModelDirectly(e){
    modelValue.value = {property: e.target.textContent};
} 
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ JSON.stringify(value, null, 4) }}
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="updateModelProperty">Update model property</button> 
  <button type="button" @click="updateModel">Update model through emit</button>
  <button type="button" @click="updateModelDirectly">Update model directly</button>
</template>

<style>
  button{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
</style>
```

- you update the property `modelValue.value.property` directly - it's ok (like you wondered). Also it goes off the `watchEffect`s radar.
- you update through `update:modelValue` - works ok, but in my example `watchEffect` is invoked (which is interesting, seems `modelValue` is became a dependency for this `watchEffect`.
- you update `modelValue.value` directly - Vue issues:

```
[Vue warn] Set operation on key "modelValue" failed: target is readonly.[object Object]
```

[**THE GIST IS HERE**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

So the solution is to use `readonly`. That way you cannot overwrite the properties but still can overwrite the property as a whole through the emit. If you provide not `readonly` value you will be able overwrite properties further:

```
<script setup>
  
  import {ref, readonly} from 'vue';
  import Child from './Child.vue';
 
    const person = ref(readonly({}));

</script>

<template>
  <child v-model="person"></child>
</template>
```

[**THE GIST IS HERE**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

If you want the readonly state preserved, provide a readonly value:

```
function updateModel(e){
    value.value = readonly({property: e.target.textContent});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here lies in the presence of a setter in your computed property:

```
 set: (value) => {
        emit('update:modelValue', value);
      },
```

According to the [doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed), whenever you assign a value to `personModel.value`, it triggers the setter, which in turn emits an update event to the parent component, causing the value to be updated.

Now, let's examine where `personModel.value` is being called. It appears to be within the `watchEffect` block:

```
  watchEffect(() => {
      personModel.value.taskIds = selectedTasks.value.map((task) => task.id);
    });
```

This `watchEffect` is triggered whenever `selectedTasks.value` changes. So, where does `selectedTasks.value` change? It seems to be in this code:

```
v-model:selected-items="selectedTasks"
```

When you use `v-model` ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model)), it enables two-way binding. In your `MultiSelect` component, it seems that you emit an event, which automatically updates the `selectedTasks` in this component.

In my opinion, you don't need the `personModel` computed property here. Instead, you can directly use the `model.value` prop for `selectedTasks` and remove the `watchEffect`. Here's an example:

```
const { modelValue } = toRefs(props);
const taskStore = useTaskStore();

const selectedTasks = ref<TaskDTO[]>(
  modelValue.value.taskIds.map(
    (taskId) => taskStore.getEntityById(taskId)! || []
  )
);
```